# Uncaught ReferenceError: makePopunder is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I get Uncaught ReferenceError: makePopunder is not defined when page load. 
I don't understand why.

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/raw/iCjRs1sQ

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

**here is your error line do not put space between closing script tag**
**your code**

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></  script>
```

**edited code**

```
<script src="something....."></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! My mistake!